# Call timed out (error 1006) - bigbluebutton

Tags: nginx, server, bigbluebutton

I have installed bigbluebutton on my serverand it was working properly but suddenly microphone can not connect anymore and after a while being stucked in "echo test" i'll get 1006 error and i have tested:

```
FreeSWITCH fails to bind to IPV4Anchor link for: freeswitch fails to bind to ipv4

In rare occasions after shutdown/restart, the FreeSWITCH database can get corrupted. This will cause FreeSWITCH to have problems binding to IPV4 address (you may see error 1006 when users try to connect).

To check, look in /opt/freeswitch/var/log/freeswitch/freeswitch.log for errors related to loading the database.

2018-10-25 11:05:11.444727 [ERR] switch_core_db.c:108 SQL ERR [unsupported file format]
2018-10-25 11:05:11.444737 [ERR] switch_core_db.c:223 SQL ERR [unsupported file format]
2018-10-25 11:05:11.444759 [NOTICE] sofia.c:5949 Started Profile internal-ipv6 [sofia_reg_internal-ipv6]
2018-10-25 11:05:11.444767 [CRIT] switch_core_sqldb.c:508 Failure to connect to CORE_DB sofia_reg_external!
2018-10-25 11:05:11.444772 [CRIT] sofia.c:3049 Cannot Open SQL Database [external]!

If you see these errors, clear the FreeSWITCH database (BigBlueButton doesn’t use the database and FreeSWITCH will recreate it on startup).

$ sudo systemctl stop freeswitch
$ rm -rf /opt/freeswitch/var/lib/freeswitch/db/*
$ sudo systemctl start freeswitch
```

but it doesn't solve the problem.

this is output of `bbb-conf --check`:

```
BigBlueButton Server 2.2.20 (2037)
                    Kernel version: 4.4.0-185-generic
                      Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (64-bit)
                            Memory: 4045 MB
                         CPU cores: 4

/usr/share/bbb-web/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties (bbb-web)
       bigbluebutton.web.serverURL: https://online.vikipoyan.ir
                defaultGuestPolicy: ALWAYS_ACCEPT
                 svgImagesRequired: true

/etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton (nginx)
                       server name: 49.12.60.238
                              port: 80, [::]:80
                              port: 443 ssl
                    bbb-client dir: /var/www/bigbluebutton

/var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml (bbb-client)
                Port test (tunnel): rtmp://online.vikipoyan.ir
                              red5: online.vikipoyan.ir
              useWebrtcIfAvailable: true

/opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/vars.xml (FreeSWITCH)
                       local_ip_v4: 49.12.60.238
                   external_rtp_ip: stun:stun.freeswitch.org
                   external_sip_ip: stun:stun.freeswitch.org

/opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/external.xml (FreeSWITCH)
                        ext-rtp-ip: $${local_ip_v4}
                        ext-sip-ip: $${local_ip_v4}
                        ws-binding: :5066
                       wss-binding: :7443

/usr/local/bigbluebutton/core/scripts/bigbluebutton.yml (record and playback)
                     playback_host: online.vikipoyan.ir
                 playback_protocol: https
                            ffmpeg: 4.2.2-1bbb1~ubuntu16.04

/etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx (sip.nginx)
                        proxy_pass: 49.12.60.238

/usr/local/bigbluebutton/bbb-webrtc-sfu/config/default.yml (Kurento SFU)
                        kurento.ip: 49.12.60.238
                       kurento.url: ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
                    kurento.sip_ip: 49.12.60.238
                    localIpAddress: 49.12.60.238
               recordScreenSharing: true
                     recordWebcams: true
                  codec_video_main: VP8
               codec_video_content: VP8

/usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/settings.yml (HTML5 client)
                             build: 968
                        kurentoUrl: wss://online.vikipoyan.ir/bbb-webrtc-sfu
                  enableListenOnly: true


# Potential problems described below
# Warning: API URL IPs do not match host:
#
#                                IP from ifconfig: 49.12.60.238
#  /var/lib/tomcat7/demo/bbb_api_conf.jsp: online.vikipoyan.ir


# Warning: The API demos are installed and accessible from:
#
#    https://online.vikipoyan.ir
#
# and
#
#    https://online.vikipoyan.ir/demo/demo1.jsp
#
# These API demos allow anyone to access your server without authentication
# to create/manage meetings and recordings. They are for testing purposes only.
# If you are running a production system, remove them by running:
#
#    apt-get purge bbb-demo

# Warning: You have this server defined for https, but in
#
#   /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx
#
#  did not find the use of https in definition for proxy_pass
#
#            proxy_pass http://49.12.60.238:5066;
#

# Warning: You have this server defined for https, but in
#
#   /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx
#
#  did not find the use of port 7443 in definition for proxy_pass
#
#            proxy_pass http://49.12.60.238:5066;
#
```

I tested everything i found and the problem still exists. is there any way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

run the command:

> sudo nano /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx

something like this will open:

```
    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://49.12.60.238:4066;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 6h;
        proxy_send_timeout 6h;
        client_body_timeout 6h;
        send_timeout 6h;
}
```

change the (proxy_pass http://...) line to the following:

```
proxy_pass https://49.12.60.238:7443;
```

Comment: I solved it a long time ago but thank you by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I followed the posts at https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/2628 but didn't get the issue resolved until I ran the following command:

```
$ wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v xenial-22 -s myserver.com -c turn.myserver.com:1004a200000000004cb3f2d6f000d85d -e johndoe@myserver.com -d -g | tee bbb-install.log
```